# Динамическое создание listitem

Tags: android, java

Исходники многоуровнего дерева для андроида в сети я не нашел, поэтому пытаюсь сам как-то изощриться. Динамически создаю итемы. Происходит это так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem(getContext(), "      " + p[i].getName().toString(), level);
    addView(item);
}
```

ListItem - класс, который наследуется он LinearLayout. Создаю динамически допустим 5 итемов (их может быть разное количество, информация берется с сервера). В правом углу списка маленькое изображине, при при клике на него открывается субитемы, при клике на субитемы открываются еще субитемы субитемов и т д. Как я могу отследить нажатие на определенный итем? Допустим есть колеллекция ArrayList, которая имеет размет такой же, что и количество итемов. При клике на итем, если бы я использовал листвью, я бы получил айди нажатого итема, и сделал бы примерно так: String s = arr.get(нажатый_итем).toString(); Но как мне сделать тоже самое, с динамически созданными итемами? Помогите пожалуйста, спасибо! Если нужно - скину полный код.

Comment: Неправильный подход - при большом количестве элементов будет жутко тормозить, а может и вовсе рухнуть. Посмотрите вот это решение: [tree-view-list-android][1] 

  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

Comment: много это сколько? максимум будет наверно 10-15.

Comment: Там же [сэмпл][1] есть.

  [1]: https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/source/browse/src/pl/polidea/treeview/demo/TreeViewListDemo.java

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: добавление элементов происходит в классе SimpleStandartAdapter вот так: " private String getDescription(final long id) {
        final Integer[] hierarchy = getManager().getHierarchyDescription(id);
        return "Node " + id + Arrays.asList(hierarchy);
    }" т.е каждый элемент будет иметь имя "Node + id". Как я могу использовать свои имена? Допустим из массива